# TIdSoapXMLDOM thread safety concerns and unusual errors in Delphi 10

Tags: delphi, indy10

Consider the following:

There's a class procedure that gets called upon receiving a HTTP/SOAP request:

- class procedure RunServiceFunction(const SoapService: TSoapService; const Req: TIdHTTPRequestInfo;...

This function has a var member "Reader: TIdSoapReaderXML;". This function eventually calls "Reader.ReadMessage(Req.PostStream, Req.ContentType, nil, nil);"

In delphi 7 this was all good. We could call the same function in parallel ad infinitum.

However, after converting the older project to Delphi 10.4, we encounter errors and crashes. Most commonly indy will raise a variety of errors:

- ERROR: undefined, socket hang up,
- ERROR: Body matches string, the given combination of arguments (undefined and string) is invalid for this assertion. You can use an array, a map, an object, a set, a string, or a weakset instead of a string
- ERROR: Body matches string, expected '\r\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap-enc="://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">soap:Bodysoap:Faultsoap:faultcodesoap:Server</soap:faultcode>soap:faultstringParser error.
  \r\nLine: 0
  \r\n</soap:faultstring><soap:detail xsi:type="EDOMParseError"/></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>\r\n' to not include 'EDOMParseError'

(http removed from the above examples due to SO limitations)

**We can fix this** by simply adding a "EnterCriticalSection" / "LeaveCriticalSection" around the "Reader.ReadMessage" - or better, by changing the Indy code therein and adding the critical section code around "FDom.Read(ASoapPacket);"

The errors only happen when calling the code in parallel (using a node.js script for example).
When calling the same code, one at a time - everything works fine. This leads me to believe it may be a thread safety issue. But, my main question is - why was this not an issue in Delphi 7? @rlebeau?

Comment: There is no `TIdSoapReaderXML` class in Indy. You are obviously dealing with custom/3rd-party code that just happens to use Indy internally. And Delphi 7 and Delphi 10.4 ship with very different versions of Indy. So I really couldn't tell you what is going on without seeing the actual code involved. But what you describe sounds like a classic race condition, which is why adding the CriticalSection appears to "fix" it.

Comment: Looks like you're right, it's IdSoap / IndySoap, which has a very similar name. At the root it uses an openXML file that's included in delphi 10 which seems to have some thread safety issues.